# Where is my deleted question and answer?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

This week, maybe on Monday, I have asked a question and self-answered it.
Since I detected a mistake in my answer, I wanted to correct it. Until I figured out what the exact answer is (I needed to identify the problematic steps), I have deleted the answer (since it was not correct) and the question (so nobody spends effort on answering something I already know).

However, I cannot find my deleted question and answer any more, even if I look in my profile "all actions".

It was a well-researched question and it will take me ~1 hour of reconstructing everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is strange; it was my understanding that you can always see your own deleted posts.

In any case, you presumably mean this:

[PyCharm 2017.3.3 hangs](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/79500/5538)

Magic!

Comment: Thanks for saving me the effort of rewriting.

Comment: You can see your own recently deleted posts by clicking 'deleted recent questions' [in your profile](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/current/?tab=questions), but they don't show up in your normal questions list and disappear after a few weeks (cc @Thomas). It probably would have been visible there (but of course not any more, as it's now undeleted!). The link isn't very obvious, and I think that's by design, though.